# Android - Is there a way to see the HTTP response when the MediaPlayer request the data source?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

We pass the URI to the media player like this:
`mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(dataSourceUri);`,
then call prepare, and start playing.

I'm wondering if it is possible to know what is the HTTP response (at least status code), after setting the data source, and media player queries the URI?

I need to know this because my Audio Player returns always MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN -1 when trying to play a song, so I was thinking it would be very helpful I could see HTTP response, and make sure the maybe the problem is on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener interface (Interface definition of a callback to be invoked to communicate some info and/or warning about the media or its playback. )

Comment: Finally I managed to know what was causing the error, by setting up and Intent and launching the native Audio Player. It turned out that the file type was not supported on Galaxy Mini. Anyway, thank you for trying to help.